# Secured SAML based IDP implementation for signed response and assertion in Azure

Tags: azure, encryption, saml-2.0

We've been trying to configure Azure Active Directory to receive encrypted SAML assertions for SSO. The application has been created in the Azure AD and has been configured to provide a signed SAML response and assertion.
Also, under Single sign-on section, we have configured the signing option and algorithm to Sign SAML response and assertion and SHA-256 respectively but we are unable to receive a proper encrypted response.

The application created is an un-listed application and the below documentation link has been used to configure the application.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-custom-apps

Can anyone please help us figure out how can we configure SP public cert at IDP in Azure so that we can receive a proper encrypted response?